# war uses jar file from peer war lib directory in ear

Tags: java, maven, jar, glassfish

Say there is a ear1, inside ear1 there are war1 and war2. Structure likes below

ear1

- lib
- war1
- war2

We use glassfish as the server and maven as the build tool. After deploy the ear1 onto glassfish, war1 got broken which because of a jar inside WEB-INF/lib of war2.

I have to pointed out this jar file is not in the lib directory of ear level or in the war1.

After remove that jar in war2 in the glassfish server application directory and restart glassfish, war1 will be ok. But the thing is war2 need that jar in order to work.

I have no idea why war1 will pick up that jar in war2 runtime and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this would be possible for you. But what if you create a project as a pom.xml (aggregator) and inside it, some different submodules (lib, war1, war2). And instead of deploying the whole ear in the server, deploy separately in the server the war1 and the war2.

Comment: @lker, we probably can't as we have to provide the whole ear to the customer.

Comment: Do you know why this will happen?

Comment: @user1311839 No idea, sorry